# How do we explain 1D triangle inequalities if there are no triangles?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The triangle inequality for reals, and metric spaces are well-known; there are questions on *proof* of it with intuition, on this site. But, my question concerned here is different, may be philosophical.

Suppose we are teaching single-variable calculus on real numbers (real line); then we can not have *triangles* in the real line! But then, what could be a good way to explain the *name* triangle inequality to the inequalities
$$|x+y|\le |x|+|y| \,\,\,\,or \,\,\,\, |x-y|\le |x|+|y|$$
etc. for any *real numbers* $x,y$?

(If $x,y$ could have been *vectors* in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$,then the second-inequality above can be phrased in words by taking three vertices $0$, $x$ and $y$ in the space, considering triangle formed by them and measuring side-lengths. But, how do we justify the name for the inequality as *triangle-inequality* in $1$-dimensional space, without moving to higher dimensions?

Or is it really the case that the name is borrowed from metric-space consideration?)

Comment: $|x+y| \leq |x| + |y|$ is the one that actually needs a proof ; the second part you state is fairly obvious and not used much :)

Comment: It is actually the same inequality. The second one is as obvious as the first. @AdityaGarg

Answer (score 3):

There are triangles on the real line, they are squashed but triangles nonetheless. Take any three points and segments joining them. If the vertices are $0$, $x$ and $y$ then $|x-y|\leq |x|+|y|$ is the triangle inequality, one side is no longer than the sum of the other two. The other one you get by replacing $y$ by $-y$. More generally, we get $|x-y|\leq |x-z|+|z-y|$.

The name is borrowed from 2D Euclidean geometry that inspired it. Although Euclid probably would not have considered degenerate triangles, with all sides on the same line, to be triangles they are typically included in modern expositions so as not to make unnecessary exceptions when stating theorems.